# Django .id usage in url function

Tags: python, django

I am currently having some fun learning Python and using Django to create a web app. I have come upon a roadblock due to my will to understand what is happening in the code. I am creating a list of links using the following code:

```
{% for topic in topics %}
        <li>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">
            {{ topic }}
        </a>
        </li>
```

I am not sure if the .id attribute is something that is built-in in Django to understand that the id of topic is to be returned. This is being passed to the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
```

Is .id some sort of function that looks for the "id" or "key" of each topic and then passes it to the regex inside the url function? Would the code stop working properly if instead of

```
<topic_id>
```

in the regex body I would have something such as

```
<topic_key>
```

- keeping everything else the same?

I appreciate your guidance. I have gone through the documentation and I feel that this is an argument that is identified as obj_id and I am thinking that .id is a way to make reference to it and some function connected with it, but I am not entirely sure - just an speculative deduction.

Thank you, Community :)

Comment: Nothing that the [docs on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#quick-example) won't answer.

Comment: Why not just try changing it to key and see what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, yes. Every model gets an `id` (or `pk`) attribute automatically when saved to the DB. It holds the id (or primary key..) of the object in the model's table.

Now let's focus on the important bits of the code:

```
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
def get_topic(topic_id):
    # magic
    return topic_with_that_id
```

And

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
for topic in topics:
    get_topic(topic.id)
```

As you can see, it doesn't really matter what is the name of the argument in
 `r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$'`, nor it matters in `{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}`, as long as you pass the correct number and types of arguments.

**An important note:** the name of the arguments in
`url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),` only matters in the view`s code, not in the template. The name you use in the template must be in accordance to your model.

Comment: Note that you can use keyword arguments in the url tag, e.g. `{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic_id=topic.id %}`. If you do this, then the variable `topic_id` must match the variable name in the url pattern and view.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank for the explanation! It makes it clear now :)